# Can two phones with different WhatsApp numbers use the same Google Drive backup?

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, google-drive

I have 2 phones with 2 different WhatsApp numbers. Both WhatsApp have their Google Drive backup enabled. However, the backup from one phone isn't visible from the other phone, I get the error of "no backup found for this account".

Can two phones with different WhatsApp numbers use the same Google Drive backup?

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can do right now. Set your backup for the second phone number and make back up. After that when you go to [Google Drive Backup](https://drive.google.com/drive/backups) address you can see two back up for two Whatsapp accounts.

[image: Google Backup Sceenshot]

Comment: This seems to contradict the statement on the What'sApp page "About Google Drive Backups" here https://faq.whatsapp.com/android/chats/about-google-drive-backups/?lang=en that says "Every time you create a Google Drive backup using the same Google account, the previous backup will be overwritten. There's no way to restore an older Google Drive backup." Could someone confirm that this works? I don't want to overwrite the backup I currently have.

Comment: As I add a screenshot above, you can have different backups for two different phone numbers. I have both of them. There is no overwrite. You can check backups from this page: https://drive.google.com/drive/backups

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tested it now myself, and I can confirm, that this works indeed. It seems like only backups for the same WhatsApp account (i.e. the same phone number) are overwritten. But it is possible to back-up two different WhatsApp accounts (two different phone numbers) on the same google drive, like described in the post. Thanks a lot for this solution!

Answer (score 0):

> Can two phones with different WhatsApp numbers use the same Google Drive backup?

Yes, and the backups will happily coexist.

My old phone had WhatsApp backing up daily to Google Drive. On the arrival of a new phone, I transferred the SIM into it, and activated a fresh SIM (with an as-yet unused number) in the old phone.

WhatsApp was installed on the new phone over Wi-Fi, and after going through the initial setup, restored the earlier chat backup from Google Drive. You can see the backup files online if you browse in [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/) to **Storage > Backups**. They have the form **WhatsApp #telephone-number# backup**

In the old phone, WhatsApp detected the phone number was no longer valid. Having validated the new number, and going to **Settings > Chats** and clicking **Back up**, that created a new backup file in the list in Google Drive, which included the new telephone number.

Comment: You wrote "WhatsApp detected the phone number was no longer valid. Having validated the new number, " <-- So then it's not really two phones with different numbesr 'cos one of them became what you call "no longer valid". I'm talking about having two phones using whatsapp using the same backup.

Comment: @barlop WhatsApp detected that the phone number had changed after the fresh SIM had been inserted (unfortunately I didn't note the exact wording at the time). The scenario answers your question, albeit I may have expressed it poorly: two phones, two different phone numbers, one Google account.

Comment: Well i'm not talking about a scenario where a "phone number changed". I'm talking about  use of two phones each with a different phone number, sharing the same whatsaspp backup.  Not somebody saying a person no longer wants their old phone number. Or like with a laptop(Even with no SIM), that can use whatsapp even without a number.